# How to check value exits in the push nodes or not android firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I have a link = "example.com"

Now I want to check whether this full tree already contains the link or not. If not then I would like to insert the data into firebase. how to do it? 
I m stuck on push `ID`, couldn't trace the link from all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, you should use a query that looks like this:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference dataRef = rootRef.child("Data");
Query query = dataRef.child(uid).orderByChild("link").equalTo("example.com");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            //Do something
        } else {
            //Do something else
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add one more field below the link, which should be unique. Then you can compare the data with that key.